# Почему приходит пустая строка?

Tags: c#

Добрый день, отсылаю серверу данные:

```
        var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Kola");
        try
        {
            client.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, 4);
        }
        catch
        {
```

Читаю:

```
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            stream.Read(buf0, 0, 4);
            MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf1));
        }
        catch
        {
```

А приходит пустая строка. Что не так?

Comment: Читать нужно в цикле, до прихода нужного числа байт. Никто не гарантирует вам, что данные придут целиком.

Comment: @VlaD А еще возможны обрывы двух "сортов" - Exception и return 0, а еще может быть нужен KeepAlive или что-то еще, но многие похоже пишут клиент-сервер ради прикола :) им это не надо :)

Comment: @SmInc: И правда. Может, напишете подробный пример кода? Для потомков.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас опечатка. buf0 и buf1. Откуда вообще второй взялся.